# ROSJAVA and Web application development (GWT)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

we are trying to build our GUI using Google Web Toolkit and ROSJAVA.
Unfortunately we are facing problems with integration of ROSJAVA into Google Web Toolkit
apps. Obviously gradle and a bootstrapping process is used to configure and start
ROSJAVA applications. Unfortunately GWT offers it's own entrypoint for applications. We
tried to add the ROSJAVA jars to the project and tried to use the NodeMainExecutor from
ROS to start a thread within the GWT server to take care for all ROS tasks.
Unfortunately due to obvious reasons this failed with ClassNotFoundException (no
bootstrapping has been performed). Now we got stuck. Is there a way to create ROSNODEs
from within a Java project without using the Java Rosrun and can the project be manually
configured without using gradle and a bootstrapping process, so that i can use the ROS
jars within my java projects avoiding ROSJAVA build process. Are their any other ways
so solve te problems like building GWT apps also via gradle? (i see problems since the
entrypoint for GWT apps is the GWT compiler)

Thank you in advance.

Kind regards,
Tim

UPDATE:
Problem is solved. The solution is to add two Maven directories (ROSJAVA and global) to gradle. This enables gradle to solve all dependencies and make ROSJAVA work. Afterwars one need to launch a ROSJAVA node on serverside by hand

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45244/rosjava-and-web-application-development-(gwt)/) by [TimB](https://answers.ros.org/users/3336/timb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-10-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2012-10-08**:
You may want to take a look at rosbridge_suite instead of rosjava: http://ros.org/wiki/rosbridge_suite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From @TimB Problem is solved. The solution is to add two Maven directories (ROSJAVA and global) to gradle. This enables gradle to solve all dependencies and make ROSJAVA work. Afterwars one need to launch a ROSJAVA node on serverside by hand

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0